# Slicing a namedtuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a namedtuple that I want to slice:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> coords = namedtuple('coords', ['lng', 'lat', 'alt'])
>>> everest = coords(86.92, 27.97, 8848)
```

So now I can access the attributes easily

```
>>> everest.alt
8848
```

However, when I want to just use the longitude and latitude, (in some geometry algorithm for example), I will slice the tuple

```
>>> flag = everest[:2]
>>> flag.lat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lat'
```

I was wondering if it was possible to slice namedtuple and keep the attributes of the sliced part alone.

Comment: Not now. The `__getitem__` method generated for the named tuple class simply doesn't implement the logic necessary to generate a new, appropriated class for the return value.

Comment: The may not be the best data structure to use. Consider a dictionary instead?

Comment: I am using tuples because I may want to use it as a key in a dict. So I need something immutable.

Comment: if you "want to just use the longitude and latitude" then use the longitude and latitude. Why is it necessary to slice out the third attribute?

Comment: why not make a class with attribute (via `@property`) location?

Comment: @7kemZmani I need to slice out the third attribute, as there is a helper library I am using that expects a tuple of length 2. It does some tuple unpacking, and there is a value error if I pass a length 3 tuple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a helper method for this that attaches a custom `__getitem__` to the namedtuple class created. The `__getitem__` will create a new class every time but with lesser number of arguments using the slice

```
from collections import namedtuple


def namedtuple_with_slice(name, args):
    cls = namedtuple(name, args)
    def getitem(self, index):
        # `type(self)` can result in issues in case of multiple inheritance.
        # But shouldn't be an issue here.
        value = super(type(self), self).__getitem__(index)
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            cls = namedtuple(name, args[index])
            cls.__getitem__ = getitem
            value = cls(*value)
        return value
    cls.__getitem__ = getitem
    return cls
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> coords = namedtuple_with_slice('coords', ['lng', 'lat', 'alt'])
>>> everest = coords(86.92, 27.97, 8848)
>>> everest[:1]
coords(lng=86.92)
>>> everest[:2]
coords(lng=86.92, lat=27.97)    
>>> everest[:3]
coords(lng=86.92, lat=27.97, alt=8848)    
>>> everest[:3][:2]
coords(lng=86.92, lat=27.97)
```